# Executing daemon process on server

Tags: c++, sockets, daemon

I have one deamon process which listen to the request from user and respond back.

While working on local system I execute it on terminal `./daemon`. When user make request `./client` from php page(executed by shell_exex() command) daemon process respond which some results. This is ok.

now I want to place this on ftp server. Php page whichc execute daemon process on button click event.

How could I make daemon process to keep listening on server continously? see daemon is c++ executable file.

One this is everytime I first execute `shell_exec(daemon)` but then purpose is lost. I want some way `daemon` process continously keep listening for the request!

Comment: this has nothing to do with php. you need to modify the daemon executable so it can run as a daemon. there's specific requirements for such a thing to occur.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`daemon()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html), it does exactly what you want.
If this function is not available on your system, take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/c-daemon-process/) which explains you how to rewrite the function.

Comment: Even if we keep as executable on ftp server, it will do same as it does on local system?

Comment: @Catty Yes, your php code will work and your server will be listening continously.

Comment: thanks. I read it but from there I could not get how to use it in my existing program!